# Can I generate an HPROF file at will?

Tags: java, hprof

I have a java process which is acting dubiously. I'd like to see what's up using the various HPROF analysis tools.

How do I generate one on the fly?

Answer (score 60):

Yes. You can generate an hprof file (containing heap memory usage) on the fly using the jmap tool, which ships with Sun's Java VM:

> jmap -dump:file=<file_name> <pid>

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Also, you can use jps to quickly find the pid of your Java process.

Answer (score 7):

You have to start the Java process with [the correct arguments,](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tooldescr-136044.html) which vary a little depending on the JVM version. Then, send a `QUIT` signal to the process to generate a new file.

> The output is normally generated when the VM exits, although this can be disabled by setting the “dump on exit” option to “n” (doe=n). In addition, a profile is generated when Ctrl-\ or Ctrl-Break (depending on platform) is pressed. On Solaris OS and Linux a profile is also generated when a QUIT signal is received (kill -QUIT pid). If Ctrl-\ or Ctrl-Break is pressed multiple times, multiple profiles are generated to the one file.

Answer (score 0):

[VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) can help you dig into what your process is doing, including the ability to arbitrarily force a heap dump on a running process.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

jconsole now has the ability to create a dump to the app's current working directory.

1. Connect to your JMX enabled instance
2. Navigate to com.sun.management-->HotspotDiagnostic-->Operations
3. Fill in p0 to name the Heap Dump
4. press the heapDump button

[Jconsole Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0vBs.png)