# Tool for gathering runtime performance metrics

Tags: java, eclipse, profiling

Anyone know of any good plugins for eclipse (Helios 3.6.1) so that I can investigate particular metrics relating to the run-time performance of a java application? It would be nice if I could get my hands on something that provides me with extensive runtime metrics such that I can investigate why a program might take longer to run than another program.

I tried TPTP documentation is out of date and I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try out [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) which has a runtime CPU and memory profiler. Or you can go with the [common stack traces method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846049/profiling-a-running-java-application-in-command-line).

Comment: Thanks for this. I had a quick look on the site there. I see it works with Eclipse. Does that include Helios (Eclipse 3.6.1)? Apologies for not specifying this in my question

Comment: VisualVM is a stand-alone application it has no connections (besides Java base) between them.